# Android Studio 2.3 start multiple emulators

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, emulation

I tried to start two emulators for the same project in the Android Studio. For the previous version, it's kind of easy. I just need to click on the run button and choose a new emulator.

After I upgraded to the Android Studio 2.3, the latest version now, it will always run in the running emulator. The dialog that asks me to select a different emulator never show up, which used to be there in the old version.

Anybody have some ideas on that? Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: screen shot]

after the first Run,

stop it by clicking the stop button (red square, top | centre)
then Re run